# как в WPF проверить завершение события SizeChanged на элементе DataGridColumnHeader?

Tags: c#, wpf

На  странице существует `DataGrid` в который динамически добавляются элементы типа `DataGridTextColumn`

```
Layers.Columns.Add(itemCollumn);
```

также описаны вот такие стили:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="#D5D505" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="S0" />
    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="ClickHeader" />
    <EventSetter Event="SizeChanged" Handler="SizeChatget" />
</Style>
```

Событие SizeCharget срабатывает при изменение ширины колонки при зажатой левой кнопки мыши, существует ли подобное событие которое сработает когда я отпущу левую кнопку мыши, то есть когда изменение ширины завершиться, или как это возможно реализовать???

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Layers"
          Grid.Row="3"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
          Width="750"
          Height="50"
          GridLinesVisibility="All" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чем вам не угодило данное событие. В качестве его параметров, передаётся объект `SizeChangedEventArgs`, который содержит свойства `NewSize` и `PreviousSize`, кроме того обратившись к свойству `System.Windows.Input.Mouse.LeftButton` можно узнать текущее состояние кнопки мыши. Так же существует такое событие как `MouseUp`, которое происходит при опускании кнопки мыши.

Comment: пожалуйста, никогда больше не вставляйте код скриншотами

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как можно это реализовать, мне нужно получить ширину элемента после изменения его ширины

Comment: только не говорите, что у вас при изменении размера хедера данные в БД записываются...

Comment: увы да, заказчик так захотел